# How to use Fiddler to monitor a Windows Service?

Tags: windows-services, fiddler

It seems that Fiddler will not monitor anything that's not run under the same user as Fiddler itself.
I would like to monitor a Windows Service which is run under `Local System`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Any reason you can't change the service to run under your own account temporarily?

Comment: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-IIS

Answer (score 13):

I made it work by referring [Is there a way to configure Fiddler to intercept HTTP calls from a Windows service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917732/is-there-a-way-to-configure-fiddler-to-intercept-http-calls-from-a-windows-servi)

> Codeka provided a clue to get me going in the right direction. The piece that was still missing was how to get the proxy configured. The `<appname>.exe.config` [needs `<defaultProxy>` specified][1] to have a section like the following added:
>
> ```xml
> <configuration>
>
>    <!-- The `<system.net>` element is an immediate child of >`<configuration>` but can appear anywhere in app.config -->
>    <system.net>
>        <defaultProxy enabled="true">
>            <proxy proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="False"/>
>        </defaultProxy>
>    </system.net>
>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> Once this was done the Windows service's http traffic started flowing
> through Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to run Fiddler as system.
This will work for services which are written in .NET and C++

To do this, I found the following application very helpful:
https://www.apreltech.com/Free/How_to_run_as_system_user

Just launch this app and accept the elevated prompt Then just browse to where you have installed Fiddler and run it.

Fiddler will launch and you should be able to see traffic from services.