# Fiddler not capturing requests from C# Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, fiddler

so I got a bit of a weird question. Fiddler captures traffic perfectly with test apps that I created. Than i moved this code to a new Windows Service that i created. 
For some magic reason I could not see any requests from Win Service in Fiddler.
The code the same, Web API, URL the same... What the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On startup, Fiddler registers itself as a system proxy, running on `127.0.0.1:8888` by default. Most of the processes use the system proxy for network access, but some don't, for example .NET applications and services, or the Mozilla Firefox browser.

To capture the traffic from such processes, you would need to change their proxy configuration settings. For example, for .NET Framework Window service, you could add [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44274184/259206) to the App.config file:

```xml
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" bypassonlocal="False"/>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```